# Is this machine AC or DC

Tags: dc-motor

I have purchased popcorn machine online. Mistakenly they send me 110V machine instead of 220V. When I saw 110V on its top I know for sure I can’t use it as I have 220v electricity in my home. So I opened up this machine that if there is anyway I can make it 220V compatible. So when I opened up I was surprise that there is no circuit in it nor any type of voltage regulator. So I am wondering this machine is even AC?

box picture
[image: l]

outside power cable
[image]

outside on/off button

[image]

inside no voltage regulator

[image]

two parts. dc motor and heating coil
[image]

dc motor 18v
[image]

dc motor back side
[image]

heating coil
[image]
this seems to be fuse with green text on it

```
SEFUSE
SF240E 
JET240 ‘C(Celsius)
  (PS)E10A 
<<<250V ~
```

any idea how to make it 220 v or make it full DC , i have dc power supply with me 36 v

**Update**
[image]

blue mean big coil terminals
red mean small heating coil terminals
[image]

Comment: Send it back and get a 240 V version.

Comment: It's just a heater. Heaters don't care whether it's AC or DC.

Comment: @winny not possible cant send back to china , too expensive to ship , will cost 10 time more than machine price , lol

Comment: Then your remaining option is to buy a new one.

Comment: Buy another one and put them in series, haha.

Comment: @Jeroen3 LOL :D

Comment: Oh my god, I never seen such a crappy electronic product! A diode rectifier built just in the motor pins!! An absolute, scary and frightening absence of any sort of protective elements! This is a complete hazard for a home. I'd just buy a better one (more expensive or from a more reputable source).

Comment: @Dark_eye - There is a thermal fuse for protection. I'm not saying that makes it a great design, of course...

Comment: @Dark_eye Most handheld hair dryers are built like this with the bridge rectifier and small DC motor- there's a thermal fuse in case the air flow gets blocked so it doesn't burn up. I don't see anything necessarily inherently bad, though the apparent translucence of the housing might indicate it's not all that flame retardant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Demand your money back!

Shipping is **on them** because this is **their mistake**.  You are correct that shipping is prohibitive, and they probably will not want the unit back.  That is fine, use it to tinker if you really want to.  **But you are entitled to a refund.  Period.**

Don't do business with those people; they don't share our values.  (shared values = we like quality things that work, our hard-earned money is valuable to us).

### You're out of luck, though

Heating elements are very cheap, and they make a separate version for 230V vs 120V.

I was trying to account for why the heating element needed 3 wires.  I was hoping it was a 240V element center-tapped and folded for the NA/JP version, but it doesn't look that way.

**The heating element is being used as a voltage divider to produce 18V for the fan**.

So yeah, not going to happen.  Sorry.

The unit will run perfectly well on DC (well, the switch will fail *instantly* since interrupting 120V DC is a great deal more difficult than interrupting 120V AC).  So you might think "Oh hey, put a diode on the 230V supply, twice the voltage half the time!"  ... Yeah, that won't work. When you double voltage to a heating element, you get 4 times the heat.  4x the heat half the time is still 2x the heat and will fry it very quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Probably made like a hair dryer with DC motor in series with the heater.

You can't realistically modify this- the heater resistance is too low, you would need to replace the heater coil with one that has around 4x the resistance (probably looks similar with thinner NiCr wire). Probably the motor would be rated for double the voltage as well since the current would be halved.

You could use an adapter or return it/trash it and get another that suits your mains voltage. **The latter would be my suggestion**.

Comment: i searched for 220v to 110v adapter but they all below 700 watts was not able to find converter which can give output of 1200w

Comment: Pretty easy to find an appropriate "2kW" one (phase control type) but I'm not going to recommend or link to it.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
The recipe below is not going to work, given the updated OP.

I second for money back as the better option. Or throw it in the trash and order a proper one (it is on the cheap side anyway).

As of 2020 there is no public electricity network with a DC customer facing. Then again, your appliance (as far as I can see from your pictures) will work on AC as well as on DC. There is a sign 50/60 Hz on it, meaning that it is intended for AC.

You can use a step-down transformer, the problem is the transformer will be probably 5x-10x more expensive than the popcorn machine itself. And heavy and bulky.

Now, if you are brave and the money are lost anyway:

Your appliance may be just the same for 220/240 market, just with different wiring of the heater element. It may as well not be.

1. Find someone electricity-literate to look what you are doing! If you can't, don't continue.
2. Check if the heating coils are two of equal-ish resistance, connected in parallel. If they are not, don't continue.
3. Get note on how the motor is powered. It may be in series w/ one of the heating coils or powered by some voltage divider. It is not clear from your photos.
4. Reconnect the two paralleled coils in series.
5. Make sure (by calculation!) the motor gets the same voltage/current as intended.
6. Replace the power plug.
7. Test in a fire-proof location by plugging it from a distance (w/ extension cord). Be ready for the fireworks if you done something wrong. Be ready to unplug it and have a bucket of sand/soil ready.

WARNING: This instruction has fire and personal safety implications. This is what I would do because I know what I am doing. Depending on where you are, it may be as well forbidden (by law) to connect an altered appliance, or an appliance made for a different voltage, to the public power grid.

Comment: hmmm there are two heating coils one big and one smaller inside it ,

Comment: @user889030 sorry, you are out of luck. There may be spare 220/240v heater elements available, but I am not sure if it is worth the hassle.

Comment: right i will play with it to see if can fix it , i have updated Question added two more pictures of it indicating coils

Comment: Ok, these pictures are enough. You can't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The "appliance" as a whole is designed for 110VAC. The heater elements don't care if it's 50Hz or 60Hz, but they DO care about the voltage. Applying 36VDC to them will get them mildly warm, not hot enough to cook anything. Applying 220V to them will result in a fire.

The little fan motor is a very cheap type that can accept very dirty DC, so they just have a simple bridge rectifier there to create it (the 4 components on the back side of the motor) and are probably putting it in series with the heater elements to drop the voltage. Bottom line, there is no way to alter this.

But... you COULD just go buy a travel adapter/voltage converter that has a little transformer to go from 220 to 110. The only problem is that you will need one rated for 1200W, so it's going to be big and not cheap. You can buy a lot of microwave popcorn for what that will cost you.